# find out how many friends accepted my App invitation using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova, whatsapp

i have an App which is developed with Phonegap/Cordova.

i want to add the functionality:
**if the user invites x friends and they installed the app, then user gets x points**.
if it is not possible then i guess i can live with:
**if the user invites x friends, then user gets x points**.

the user can invite friends over facebook, Whatsapp, (Email)

my questions are:

1. is there away to achieve this "ensure invited and installed"
   functionality?
2. i have seen the Facebook Api provides a similar functionality, what about WhatsApp?, or Email?

Thank you for your hints

Comment: How to invite people on Facebook is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

Comment: thank you, i mentioned that i know it exists for facebook, do you know if a whatsapp solution exists?

Comment: _“if it is not possible then i guess i can live with: if the user invites x friends, then user gets x points”_ – that one Facebook doesn’t allow. You are only allowed to reward for _successful_ invites when using the official invite mechanism for Game apps with a canvas platform. Rewarding people for just sending out invites would encourage spammy behavior.

Comment: try to post an unique number to server from your application.

Comment: but how will this work if the user shares the link over whatsapp?, in facebook API, i have seen that it returns the number of users invited.

Answer (score 1):

Track them using a token:

```
To download, click this link:
yourserver.com/download/?token=user123456
```

Store the token/user combination in a datatabase, and when this site is opened count up the earning of a user.

Comment: Hello Jonas, it will allow then for duplicates, do you think, a solution exists not to allow duplicates?

Comment: Just delete the token in your database when the site was opened... And share different links,i dont know any other way

Comment: thanks @Jonas w: but how will this work if the user shares the link over whatsapp?, in facebook API, i have seen that it returns the number of users invited.

Comment: @Augustus: no way